What is the specific process of the BA variant of the Dolev-Strong protocol?
The Dolev-Strong protocol can securely operate in environments with malicious majorities and has a round complexity of $f+1$. The paper "Improved Extension Protocols for Byzantine
Broadcast and Agreement" mentions: “The Dolev-Strong protocol can also be modified to solve authenticated Byzantine Agreement (BA) for the $t < n/2$ case (BA is impossible if $t \geq n/2$). Using an initial all-to-all round with multi-signature to simulate the sender.” In my view, this differs from the common approach of converting between BB and BA (i.e., running $n$ parallel BBs to achieve BA). According to the approach described in the paper, if in round 0 all replicas send their values (assuming the values are only 0 or 1), and in round 1, honest nodes fail to generate valid aggregated signatures (but receive at least $f+1$ messages), while a malicious node receives $f+1$ identical values and generates an aggregated signature, this malicious node could withhold the value until round $f$, and then in that round send a value with $f+1$ signatures to any honest node, thereby compromising the agreement of BA. I believe my understanding might be incorrect. Therefore, I would like to know the specific process of the BA variant of the Dolev-Strong protocol.
